# **You didn't pass** in review queue, Is this a mistake?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

When I was in the **review queue**

I reviewed a very good Answer, but, the user's name wasn't showing up, also the image, 0 upvotes

I wanted to upvote it as the first upvoter cause I liked both question and answer, But before I do that, I wanted to see some other answers to that question too cause It really got my interest

I clicked on the question and opened it in a new tab, I saw an **upvoted +80 Answer** that's **exactly** like the one I reviewed it
I was sad cause I thought the one **in the review** copy-pasted it just to get reputations like the OP of that good answer. that's against the rules to duplicate a post so I went to downvote it
Because it's just a pure duplicate of an **existing** answer, I downvoted and before I even flag...
Suddenly appears a message that says

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You
>   didn't pass**. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high-quality
>   post...

It turns out that this was a Test and I fail, **lost** reputations, and maybe **the truth** of SO
for no reason...please, how can I fix this error or tell a moderator, I think it's just a system mistake...
[Does C++11, 14, 17 or 20 introduce a standard constant for pi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49778493/8524922)

Comment: Quick nitpick: you can't lose rep from a failed audit. In any case, You were shown a 'fake' version of that very good answer. If they show you an answer at +80 you'll know to upvote. It's not someone who posted this as a copy. They simply hid the score in the review. But yeah that order of event and train of thought makes sense for a user unused to reviews  and audits. Kinda sucks for you :/. Are you banned from that audit?

Comment: Idea: maybe the act of viewing the original should cancel the audit, for this type of audit.

Comment: @user2357112 The issue there is that the trick will quickly be known and abused by robo reviewers, I guess.

Comment: @Patrice: A userscript could probably pass most audits already by looking for discrepancies between the audit and the original. I don't know if this change would make things substantially easier for robo-reviewers, particularly if combined with some sort of analysis of how quickly they leave the page or something like that.

Comment: @Patrice I don't know if I'm banned, I just stopped cause that was really bad accusation for me.

Comment: Happen to have a link to that review task? I'm showing that https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19587198 is the last audit that post was used in, and that was by a different user and was passed. Neither of [your two reviews today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8524922/kira-sama?tab=activity&sort=reviews) were audits, and my tools don't show *any* audits in the last 24 hours for you in First Posts or Late Answers.

Comment: It turned out that I lost reputations because of down-voting some unclear/comment-like answers (it takes time to lose reputations so I lost exactly at this **event** occurrence so I thought that event was the reason for losing), Sorry. @Undo that's exactly the link that I was in, I think ***tests*** like this doesn't show up in "reviews" or maybe If I had taken the right Action, It'd have appeared.

Comment: Failed audits definitely show up in at least one of the views I'm looking at. Are you sure this occurred recently, in the last day or so?

Comment: Yes, This just occurred today before posting this question on meta with some minutes, I remember clicking a button like "I understand" when this message appeared, Do it has something to do?

Comment: @KiraSama the audit system is very flawed.  You will have to get use to it.  I've been wrongly banned here several times.  Complaining to the moderates won't help either,  they will nit pick your reviews and sometimes ban you longer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not a mistake, it's just a nuance of the review process.

Review audits are questions and answers selected by the system through some complicated algorithm, some that are reasonably good posts and some that are already deleted. This way the system can check if people are giving good quality reviews to things.

However, to make it look like a normal question or answer and obviously be an audit, a couple things are changed: vote counts are usually set to 0, and posts that are actually deleted appear normal until you finish the audit and the system tells you if you passed or not.

Being aware of this will help you avoid failing future audits. If you ever see a post that has a different vote count or something is funny with the username in the review queue, or you see a duplicate question or answer when you go to the real question, then it is probably an audit. What you could have done in your case where you thought it was a duplicate answer would have been to look at all the answers for the question to make sure it's not there twice, which would confirm your suspicions about it being an audit. If it is there twice, then a flag indicating the issue is the way to go, and if you're nervous about failing an audit because you aren't sure which of the two answers you are looking at in the review queue, then you can hit skip and handle the flagging on the actual question's window.

Two other comments:

You don't lose rep or spend flags or anything on an audit, so don't worry, you didn't lose anything.

Also, if by "fix this error" you mean change your review history to show the audit as not failed or something, just don't worry about it. Everyone makes a mistake once in a while, but as long as you aren't repeatedly failing audits, there won't be any consequence.

Comment: Thanks, I think I learned though, also, I meant fixing this (for all) as I thought there're people that might fail in this injustice way as me too, so I wanted a more ***accurate*** system. btw, nice answer. :)

Comment: "through some complicated algorithm" It's not very complicated, it's just bad.

Comment: Actually, you only have to fail one audit to be banned, if you have made a similar mistake on lots of other, real questions.

Comment: @TylerH In my experience those two things are related more often than you would expect.

Comment: "What you could have done in your case where you thought it was a duplicate answer would have been to look at all the answers for the question to make sure it's not there twice" -- Worth mentioning, perhaps: if it's not there, there can be two reasons: either it was an audit for a good answer, or it was an audit for a duplicate answer which has already been deleted. Without the ability to see deleted answers, you cannot know for sure which of the two applies (even if one is more likely), so you cannot know which action will pass the audit. Your suggestion to skip is a good one.